# node.js variables will not be parsed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, ejs

i am new in node.js and express.

in my test app the html variables will not be parsed.
what is the problem?

server.js

```
enter var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended : true
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        wert : 'hallo'
    });
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var wert = req.body.wert;
    var html = 'Hallo: '+wert+'!\n'
    + '<a href="/">Mach\'s nochmal!</a>';
    res.send(html);
});
app.listen(8882);
console.log('Server port: 8882');
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Startseite</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hallo <%= wert %>, dies ist mein kleiner Webserver!</p>
<br>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" width="40" name="wert" value="<%= wert %>"> 
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the value parameter <%= wert %> in the view is not parsed.
why? how to do it?

thank you
jet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you ben,

your `ejs` configuration was good.
I had to install `express`, `ejs`, `body-parser`. that was ok.
then i had to remove the line with `app.use(express.static(__dirname));`

and i had to change

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

to 
app.set('views', __dirname);
```

for my original path.

then everything was ok!

greez
jet

Answer (score 3):

Express doesn't come with a view-engine by default. You need to add one, in your case [EJS](https://github.com/tj/ejs).

Using the command line, type:

```
npm install ejs
```

server.js now becomes:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended : true
}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        wert: 'hallo'
    });
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var wert = req.body.wert;
    res.render('index', {
        wert: wert
    });
});
app.listen(8882);
```